# Как из хранилища vuex вызывать методы в компонентах?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Компонент дает команду Vuex сделать асинхронный запрос, который загружает данные в хранилище, но как компонент может "узнать", что данные загружены?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хранилище не должно ничего знать о компонентах, иначе это нарушение инкапсуляции.
Возвращайте промис, чтобы его обработать на стороне клиента:

```
this.$store.dispatch('action').then(() => {
  // здесь данные загружены, делаем обработку
})
```

Также можно завести флаг в хранилище и отслеживать его изменение в компоненте. Перед загрузкой данных выставляем флаг в состояние загрузки, после того, как данные получены - снимаем.

Comment: Этот код для компонента или для Store?

Comment: Для компонента.

Comment: Для компонента.